# Is it possible to compare doubly compressed files?

Tags: linux, compression

I'm working on a script to compare files from two paths, these files can be quite large so they have been compressed twice, first with gzip then with bzip2, so the file extension is file.gz.bz2. I'd like to compare the files without having to de-compress them, is this possible?

Comment: If the files are identical without compression they are identical with compression too.. or what you want to compare?

Comment: @Hardy: Not true.  gzip's metadata includes time of creation.

Answer (score 1):

No.  You'll need to at least decompress the bzip2.  Then if you know for a fact that both gzip executions used the same code at the same compression level, then you can compare just the compressed data.  Otherwise the best you can do without decompressing the gzip is to compare the length and CRC at the end of the gzip.  If they match, then there is a very high probability that the uncompressed data will match.